# "Thanks for the feedback" notification persists for less than four seconds

Tags: discussion, feature-request, android-app, notification-bar

I downvoted an answer in the Stack Exchange Android app and I got a notification at the top of the app saying

> Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 125 reputation are recorded but do not display the publicly displayed post score.

But this message closes very fast (barely four seconds). For a person who has fluency in English, it can be read very fast but for a new English learning person they have to down vote again and again to read it again or have to take a screenshot just like I did today. Why is it like that?

Why we can't have more than 10 seconds or an option to close the message as per users wish?

[image: Feedback]